# 2 reselect input selectors share too much code. How to refactor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to select garages and retailers based on a selected city.

Thats what I have right now:

```
const garagesSelector = state => state.garages
const retailersSelector = state => state.retailers
const selectedCitySelector = state => state.cities.selected

const garagesInCitySelector = createSelector(
  garagesSelector,
  selectedCity,
  (garages, city_id) => garages.filter(garage => garage.city_id === city_id)
)

const retailersInCitySelector = createSelector(
  retailersSelector,
  selectedCity,
  (retailers, city_id) => retailers.filter(retailer => retailer.city_id === city_id)
)
```

They basically do the same just the items selector they operate on differs.
I imagine a construct where the `items` can be any selector that returns an array.

Something like:

```
const inCitySelector = createSelector(
  items,
  selectedCity,
  (items, city_id) => items.filter(garage => item.city_id === city_id)
)
const garagesInCitySelector = inCitySelector(garagesSelector)
const retailersInCitySelector = inCitySelector(retailersSelector)
```

**Update:**

```
const filterByCity = (items, city_id) => item => item.city_id === city_id

const garagesInCitySelector = createSelector(garagesSelector, selectedCity, filterByCity)
const retailersInCitySelector = createSelector(retailersSelector, selectedCity, filterByCity)
```

But it seems still too much code to me.